# Rancher 2.2.1 - Cert expiration after 1 year

Tags: linux, kubernetes, rancher

Actually I running a Rancher single node instance installed from Rancher UI.
After 1 year, Rancher UI is unusable and I've these logs:
[image: Rancher Error logs]

After investigation, I found another cert error on container `k8s_agent_cattle-node-agent-XXXX_cattle-system_XXXX`: [image: Error cattle]

After 1 year Rancher UI cert is expired, How can I renew it ?
I'm running Rancher UI 2.2.1.

Thanks a lot.

Best Regard.

Comment: what have u tried?

Comment: Hi, I tried to re create certificate from ca inside oo /opt/rancher/management-state/tls/ but doesnt works

Comment: Could you please paste those logs as `code sample` not as photos? It would make it much easier to read it.